# How to use Reactjs with routing feature in a single page of Wordpress theme without affecting other page url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, reactjs, url

I have an education site called MCQ Academy which is built with Wordpress. This website contain a page to enable visitor to make a test. The page is `https://mcqacademy.com/start-mcq-test/?lang=en&topic=english-grammar` . This page currently shows 20 questions currently.

I have hired a developer to use Reactjs with routing feature to paginate the questions in 4 pages. Every page will show 5 questions and the last page will also have a submit button.

Now my developer said that the url will be changed to `https://mcqacademy.com/start-mcq-test/#/lang-en/topic/english-grammar/page-1` to use reactjs routing. I want the URL matching `https://mcqacademy.com/start-mcq-test/lang-en/english-grammar/page-1`

Problem is, I don't want the /#/ in the url as it is not seo friendly and the part of url after /#/ is not rendered at server. Is it possible to use Reactjs routing to work on specific wordpress page without affecting other page url of the website and also avoid the /#/ in url while navigate in the reactjs enabled page.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: IMO your dev should be using `BrowserRouter` (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) instead of `HashRouter` (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)

Comment: @palsrealm I've used BrowserRouter it haven't work for me, but here is an answer, may give you some idea.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually#answer-36623117

Comment: And if you want you can completely change the template leveraging client side routing, not part of it.

Comment: On page refresh it will search for the route on the server, which isn't available, so will show error

Comment: To use a non-hashed URL and still be fully functional, you could set up a catch-all route server-side for your test subdirectory, always serve the same template & bundle.js, and let react-router handle the routing and rendering the proper page.